# How to add/merge two tables on primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm a total SQL newbie. I have two tables. Each table has a primary key column (`ID`) and several other columns with integer values.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Now I want to merge both tables into one table - in a way that all apples, bananas and tomatoes are added per ID.

For example:

[image]

How does the SQL statement looks like for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have no time to test it, but I would use a UNION and a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT ID,
    SUM(APPLES) AS APPLES,
    SUM(BANANAS) AS BANANAS,
    SUM(TOMATOES) AS TOMATOES
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM TABLEA 
              UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM TABLEB ) AS ALL
GROUP BY ID
```

If it works, this first creates a table with all entries and then combines the ones with the same ID. Anyone feel free to edit if there are problems.

Didn't see you want a third table, you don't need the column aliases then:

```
INSERT INTO
    TABLEC
VALUES
    (ID, APPLES, BANANAS, TOMATOES)
SELECT ID,
    SUM(APPLES),
    SUM(BANANAS),
    SUM(TOMATOES)
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM TABLEA 
              UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM TABLEB) AS ALL
GROUP BY ID
```

If that doesn't work, you can do one of the JOIN answers, but would change it to TABLEA JOIN TABLEB USING(ID).

Answer (score 5):

```
    INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (ID, Apples, Bananas, Tomatoes)
     SELECT ISNULL(a.Id, b.Id) as [Id], 
             ISNULL(a.Apples,0) + ISNULL(b.Apples,0) AS [Apples], 
             ISNULL(a.Bananas,0) + ISNULL(b.Bananas,0) AS [Bananas], 
             ISNULL(a.Tomatoes,0) + ISNULL(b.Tomatoes,0) AS [Tomatoes]
    FROM Table1 AS a
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS b on b.Id = a.Id
```

I think this will solve your issue. Just a `INSERT` and a `SELECT` combined.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is it probably needs to be a `full outer join` since in his example not all ids are in both tables. Because of this it would also probably be necessary to add `isnull()` to avoid something like `null + 5`.

Comment: Thanks @SQLChao, I had missed that. I'll wrap the columns individually in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use a full outer join, otherwise you may miss some id's. In your example, with left join you will miss id=4, while with right join you will miss id= 2.

Also be carefull with the ID, you want to take it from Table1 if exists, id from Table2 otherwise

So the best solution i think is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ID, Apples, Bananas, Tomatoes)
SELECT  coalesce (a.Id, b.Id) 
coalesce(a.Apples, 0) + coalesce(b.Apples, 0)  AS Apples, 
coalesce(a.Bananas, 0) + coalesce(b.Bananas, 0) AS Bananas, 
coalesce(a.Tomatoes, 0) + coalesce(b.Tomatoes, 0) AS Tomatoes, 
FROM Table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 b on b.Id = a.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into tableC (ID, Apples, Bananas, Tomatoes)
select tableA.ID,
       ISNULL(tableA.Apples,0) + ISNULL(tableB.Apples,0) as Apples,
       ISNULL(tableA.Bananas,0) + ISNULL(tableB.Bananas,0) as Bananas,
       ISNULL(tableA.Tomatoes,0) + ISNULL(tableB.Tomatoes,0) as Tomatoes
from tableA left join tableB
on tableA.ID = tableB.ID;
```